Ubuntu 22: Terminal and File explorer are less responsive
I am using a HP ZBook 15 G6 laptop which had no problem on Ubuntu 20.04.
After an upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04:

Terminal is less responsive after a few minutes: sometimes letters are displayed about 1 second after typing it on my keyboard (I use gnome-terminal and I have the same problem with terminator, I haven't tested other terminal emulators)

Nautilus is also less responsive: content of directory can be displayed several seconds after double click on it. Moreover there is some flickering when the content is displayed.


Other applications work well: google chrome, firefox, vscode, qt creator, virtual box, docker...
Any idea or debugging method is very welcome :-)

Does this answer your question? input delay on Terminal Ubuntu 22.04.4

I am currently testing it, it looks fine, thanks a lot !
